# Evolution strategies global recombination question

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms

In evolution strategies the genotype has object variables and strategy variables as alleles (and sometimes the alpha values).

I'm reading the book Introduction to Evolutionary Computing (A.E. Eiben, J.E. Smith) and there is something that I don't understand:

> An extension of this scheme allows the use of more than two
>   recombinants, because the two parents x and y are drawn randomly for
>   each position i {1,...,n} in the offspring anew.

I don't understand what the `n` value is:

1. The number of object variables.
2. The number of strategy parameters.
3. The number of object variables + the number of strategy parameters.

What is the correct value of `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: http://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/~nijssensgr/CI/2012/9%20genetic%20algorithm.pdf

"Per offspring gene two parent genes are involved
Choices:
-combination of  two parent genes: 
--average value of parents (intermediate recombination)
--value of one randomly selected parent (discrete recombination)
-choice of parents:
--a different pair of parents for each gene (global recombination) 
--the same pair of parents for all genes"